# ES2015 testing - mocking and code coverage

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, code-coverage, ecmascript-6

In CommonJS pattern one could use [mockery](https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery) or [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) to mock the dependency.

How do I mock dependency in ES2015 testing?

What to use for ES2015 code coverage? [Istanbul](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul) does not seem to work.

Any pointer would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Dependency Injection, through dependency inversion. Make your classes depend on abstractions instead of concrete details.

Answer (score 0):

For mocking dependency, [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) holds good.

For code coverage, [nyc](https://github.com/bcoe/nyc) serves the purpose.

```
"lint": "eslint ./src/* ./test/*",
"unit-test": "nyc --reporter=lcov mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register",
"coverage": "nyc check-coverage --statement 100 --branches 100 --function 100 --lines 100",
"test": "npm run lint && npm run unit-test --coverage && npm run coverage",
```

Refer this [package.json](https://gitlab.com/sarbbottam/interview-questions/blob/master/package.json#L7-10)